# Object method considered as string

Tags: javascript, function, object

I'm defining a very simple object which should calculate the sum of number 1 & 2 :

```
function Calculator() {
    this.number1 = 0;
    this.number2 = 0;
    this.sum = function() {
        return this.number1 + this.number2;
    }
}

var calculator = new Calculator();
calculator.number1 = 1;
calculator.number2 = 2;

console.log(calculator.sum);
```

However when I run the "sum" method, the console returns :

```
function() {
        return this.number1 + this.number2;
    }
```

It's like my method was considered as a string but I can't understand why...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to call it. Use:

```
console.log(calculator.sum());
```

Your method wasn't considered a string. What happens is that `calculator.sum` is a variable that holds a function. Logging it without calling will just return its body.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, is *not* "considered" as a string: `sum` is considered as *function*. But, because you're trying to "dump" a function reference, and you can only dump text, JavaScript needs to ask what is the string representation of that object. And the string representation of that object is the function's source. So basically having:

```
console.log(calculator.sum);
```

It's the same to have:

```
console.log(calculator.sum.toString());
```

That's because `log` needs a string to dump and tries to convert the argument in something it can display. Notice also that this behavior depends by the console you're using. For instance, the web console of Firefox returns `[object Function]` (because it use the `Object.prototype.toString` instead of the function's one) where the Chrome web console returns the function's `toString` method.

In your case you want to probably invoke the method, and therefore you forgot the parenthesis:

```
console.log(calculator.sum());
```

However, the reason because you do not got any error when you try to log the `calculator.sum` without the parenthesis, it's because JavaScript has [first-class function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function). It's a very powerful thing, that gives to you the ability to pass function as arguments of other function, like you did. So for example you can have:

```
function log(thing) {
    console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(thing));
}

log(1);
log("something");
log(function foo() {});
```

Of course you can also invoke a function passed as argument:

```
function say(something) {
    alert(something());
}

function hello() { return "Hello!" };
function bye() { return "Bye!" };

say(hello);
say(bye);
```

Those are just silly examples, but just to give you an idea.